# How can I drag and drop Views within Android RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, drag-and-drop

I made my own drag and drop functionality.

I wanted to do this with a `RelativeLayout`, but this seems not to work very well.
At the beginning i can tell each `View` I want to drag on which position it should be by setting it below the `View` before.

But when I want to drag a View, all the other Views beneath it are moved too, because they want to keep the order in which I set them.

But what other layout can I use for this? I have to use this drag and drop functionality on different screen sizes, so I cant' give them fixed `x` and `y` values.

Comment: Which Layout i should use.
Because with RelativeLayout i cant do this how i want...

Comment: I use (grid) drag and drop in my application with a pure custom layout. That means deriving from ViewGroup.

Comment: Grid i see.. mhh... so i can add my Views (RelativeLayout) to the Grid View, and i can drag every one on its own, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I faced the same trouble a while ago, if you do not want to drag other views (either below or above or beside your view) along with the view being dragged, then use `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` instead of `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, the latter is imported if you hit Ctrl-Shift-O, so change it manually to the former.

Edit: Since you wanted the description of how I achieved that, here is the actual code

```
 MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(image.getLayoutParams());              
 int left = (int) event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2);
 int top = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
 marginParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
 image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

I had to do a lot of research to achieve the same and it took me 2 days to figure out that a thing called MarginLayoutParams exists...

Make sure that you have

```
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams;
```

as your imports and not `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`.

Also make sure that you cast marginparams to your relative layout
Best of luck...

Comment: could you tell me how you are moving your views?

because i was doing it with:

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);                     
           params.leftMargin = x-75;
           params.topMargin  = y-25;     
     
     currentlyDraggedRectangle.setLayoutParams(params);

but this doesnt work anymore with ViewGroup

Comment: mhh.. thank you! but its difficult... my Custom View extends RelativeLayout, and i have to import it...