# Positioning items relative to the ActionBar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-view

I used to have an Activity that would use no ActionBar. The layout is a `RelativeLayout` with width and height simply matching the parent. It allowed users to drag around buttons using [parts of this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073304/how-can-i-drag-and-drop-views-within-android-relativelayout/10075146#10075146) in the `onTouch` event:

```
MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(v.getLayoutParams());
int left = (int) event.getRawX() - (v.getWidth() / 2);
int top  = (int) event.getRawY() - (v.getHeight());
marginParams.setMargins(left, top, 0, 0);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

All dandy—the button moves just below the finger and is placed correctly at the position on screen. Now, however, I enabled the ActionBar, and suddenly when clicked, the button moves ~30 pixels *below* the finger. To illustrate this behavior, here's what I used to have (on the left) and what happens right now (on the right):

[image]

I assume this is because the ActionBar now displaces everything by its own height. Of course, I do not want this to happen, or at least correct this, so:

- How can I shift the placement in `setMargins()` according to the actual size of the ActionBar without using a hardcoded value?
- How can I prevent the ActionBar from shifting everything in the first place? Put differently, how can I ensure my button is placed relative to the ActionBar's bottom line and directly where the finger points?

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't consider `.setMargins(left, top - 35, 0, 0);` a very useful solution by the way.

Answer (score 0):

(I used an approach is my code and it works. I am going to tell you the same here)

- I think `setMargin()` is not such a clever thing to use here. Instead you can use `setX()` and `setY()` methods.
- Whenever one switches over from a full screen activity to the one with Action Bar, one runs into such problem.
  You will need to adjust for the Action Bar height. Instead of using `getLayoutParams()`, use  `getLocationInWindow()` or `getLocationOnScreen()`. Since `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` work with screen positions of the view, these APIs should be used.